# Remove value from Array of Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

How I can remove a dict from an array of dictionaries?

I have an array of dictionaries like so: `var posts = [[String:String]]()` - and I would like to remove a dictionary with a specific key, how would I proceed? I know that I can remove a value from a standard array by doing `Array.removeAtIndex(_:)` or a dictionary key by doing `key.removeValue()`, but an array of dictionaries is more tricky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to remove a dictionary with a specific key"? If you have an array of 3 dictionaries, and 2 of them have the key `foo`, do you want them to be all removed? Just the first?

Comment: @AMomchilov I want to remove the dictionary with the specific key 'foo', as I know for a fact that all the keys in the array of dictionaries are unique keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you questions correctly, this should work

```
var posts: [[String:String]] = [
    ["a": "1", "b": "2"],
    ["x": "3", "y": "4"],
    ["a": "5", "y": "6"]
]

for (index, var post) in posts.enumerate() {
    post.removeValueForKey("a")
    posts[index] = post
}

/* 
This will posts = [
    ["b": "2"], 
    ["y": "4", "x": "3"], 
    ["y": "6"]
]
*/
```

Since both your dictionary and the wrapping array are value types just modifying the `post` inside of the loop would modify a copy of dictionary (we created it by declaring it using `var`), so to conclude we need to set the value at `index` to the newly modified version of the dictionary

Answer (score 3):

## Removing all Dictionaries with a given key

```
let input = [
    [
        "Key 1" : "Value 1",
        "Key 2" : "Value 2",
    ],
    [
        "Key 1" : "Value 1",
        "Key 2" : "Value 2",
    ],
    [
        "Key 1" : "Value 1",
        "Key 2" : "Value 2",
        "Key 3" : "Value 3",
    ],
]

let keyToRemove = "Key 3"

//keep dicts only if their value for keyToRemove is nil (meaning key doesn't exist)
let result = input.filter{ $0[keyToRemove] == nil }

print("Input:\n")
dump(input)
print("\n\nAfter removing all dicts which have the key \"\(keyToRemove)\":\n")
dump(result)
```

You can see this code in action [here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/577c2158fc6e90d25e4ad064).

## Removing the only the first Dictionary with a given key

```
var result = input
//keep dicts only if their value for keyToRemove is nil (meaning key doesn't exist)
for (index, dict) in result.enumerate() {
    if (dict[keyToRemove] != nil) { result.removeAtIndex(index) }
}

print("Input:\n")
dump(input)
print("\n\nAfter removing all dicts which have the key \"\(keyToRemove)\":\n")
dump(result)
```

You can see this code in action [here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/577c244bfc6e90d25e4ad066).

Comment: The first code (what I am looking for) does not seem to work. I tried to use this code, and print the array of dictionaries afterwards, with no luck. The data was not removed. This is strange..

Comment: Have a link below that code snippet that shows it working fine